# Image container instead of event object in image load event handler

Tags: javascript, image, events, load

I stumbled upon a very strange thing. In FF 3.6 (not tested others yet) I add onload handler to an image like this:

```
imgRef.addEventListener("load", activateLink, false);
```

When load event fires, in activateLink(evt) the evt paramater is not an event, but the "a" tag that contains the image. Why is this?

```
function activateLink(evt) {
  // evt turns out to be a refference to <a> tag (HTMLAnchorElement) that contains the image.
  // Actually two of them. Both dynamically added with addElement.
}
```

I remembered another fact that may be relevant. I have multiple images with the same src that all have registered this same event handler activateLink. Could this be the problem?

Comment: can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: Not sure why exactly.  Check the evt.currentTarget and see if it has the img obj reference.

Comment: I have more than 4000 lines of JS code. I am pretty sure most of it is not relevant to this issue. I will try to update with more code and information, that could have something to do with it. But without some kind of lead I don't have a clue what to post.

Comment: I *think* amosrivera really just wants to know how you get `imgRef` to make sure that there isn't a simple mistake.

Comment: Guys I realized that this is not even event object, it is an actual reference to the <a> tag dom element. Chrome does it too, super strange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause, I actually call this method by myself with the a tag as parameter. Forgot to change the reference on one place. Stupid javascript and its loose types :( Stupid mistake.